# Wamp showing the wrong version of php even when updated

Tags: php, wamp, wampserver, wamp64

I got a problem since some weeks with WampServer. When I click on the Wamp's icon it shows me that the current PHP version used by Wamp is PHP 5.6 and when I try to change the version it still shows me the 5.6 PHP version BUT in my phpinfo() the version is updated.

Do you know why the display of Wamp is wrong ?

I'm using 3.1.9 Wamp version by the way.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: If the `phpinfo()` version is correct it shouldn't be a problem because that's what version is being used. Here's a thread with a similar issue https://superuser.com/questions/969861/phpinfo-and-php-v-shows-different-version-of-php/1190483

Comment: Thanks for your reply, ok if it's not a problem that's fine then but i got the same issue when i try to update wamp to 3.2 it still shows me wamp 3.1.9 idk why i guess i should try to uninstall and install it properly.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me and I found that clearing the PHP error log solved the problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).